# Apache Spark WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space

Tags: apache-spark

I use Sparklung Water and I'm reading data from a parquet file.

The part of my spark-default.conf:

```
`spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max 1g 
spark.driver.memory 40g 
spark.executor.memory 40g 
spark.driver.maxResultSize 0 
spark.python.worker.memory 30g 
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution 
spark.storage.safetyFraction 0.9 
spark.storage.memoryFraction 0.0
```

`

```
15/11/26 11:44:46 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_7_472 in memory! (computed 3.2 MB so far) 
15/11/26 11:44:46 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl 
15/11/26 11:44:46 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl 
15/11/26 11:44:46 WARN MemoryStore: Failed to reserve initial memory threshold of 1024.0 KB for computing block rdd_7_474 in memory. 
15/11/26 11:44:46 WARN MemoryStore: Failed to reserve initial memory threshold of 1024.0 KB for computing block rdd_7_475 in memory.
```

Really, Spark uses only a part of memory which it can use and there are a lot of errors about allocation memory. And Spark starts to write data on a hard drive instead of using RAM. Why it does so? May be I should change something in the conf file? And how can I change a directory which Java uses as a "tmp"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Case if you land into this post and still wondering what is going on, please refer to above answer to how and why you landed to this error.

For me I would really look in`(computed 3.2 MB so far)` and start to worry!

However, in order to resolve:
Set `spark.storage.memoryFraction` flag to `1` while creating the `sparkContext` to utilize upto XXGb of your memory, default it 0.6 of the total memory provided. 
Also consider setting:

`rdd.compression` to `true`

and

`StorageLevel` as `MEMORY_ONLY_SER` if your data is kind of larger than your available memory. (you could try `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` also).

Just went through old mails and stumble upon this properties:

```
**spark.shuffle.spill.numElementsForceSpillThreshold**
```

we set it to **--conf spark.shuffle.spill.numElementsForceSpillThreshold=50000** which resolved the issue, however this value needs to be twerked for specific use case(try lowering the value to 40000 or 30000).

As of this date, spark has two new parameters:
- `spark.shuffle.spill.map.maxRecordsSizeForSpillThreshold`
- `spark.shuffle.spill.reduce.maxRecordsSizeForSpillThreshold`

Reference:

> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27734

Hope it helps!Cheers!

Comment: Please look at this: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Spark-shuffle-spill-Memory/td-p/186859

Comment: In one of our cases, we have resolved similar issue, by playing with --conf spark.shuffle.spill.numElementsForceSpillThreshold=50000. Although for large shuffles: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27734

Answer (score 0):

*And Spark starts to write data on a hard drive instead of using RAM. Why it does so?*

It should be because somewhere your settings for persistence are configured to use the option **MEMORY_AND_DISK**.

From the docs --> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence
From the source code -> https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/memory/MemoryStore.scala

```
private case class DeserializedMemoryEntry[T](
value: Array[T],
size: Long,
classTag: ClassTag[T]) extends MemoryEntry[T] {
val memoryMode: MemoryMode = MemoryMode.ON_HEAP
}
```

and this bit

```
// Initial memory to request before unrolling any block
private val unrollMemoryThreshold: Long =
conf.get(STORAGE_UNROLL_MEMORY_THRESHOLD)
```

Further down you find this bit

```
// Whether there is still enough memory for us to continue unrolling this block
var keepUnrolling = true
// Initial per-task memory to request for unrolling blocks (bytes).
val initialMemoryThreshold = unrollMemoryThreshold
// How often to check whether we need to request more memory
val memoryCheckPeriod = conf.get(UNROLL_MEMORY_CHECK_PERIOD)
// Memory currently reserved by this task for this particular unrolling operation
var memoryThreshold = initialMemoryThreshold
// Memory to request as a multiple of current vector size
val memoryGrowthFactor = conf.get(UNROLL_MEMORY_GROWTH_FACTOR)
// Keep track of unroll memory used by this particular block / putIterator() operation
var unrollMemoryUsedByThisBlock = 0L
```

and this is the where the error you see comes from

```
    // Request enough memory to begin unrolling
keepUnrolling =
  reserveUnrollMemoryForThisTask(blockId, initialMemoryThreshold, memoryMode)

if (!keepUnrolling) {
  logWarning(s"Failed to reserve initial memory threshold of " +
    s"${Utils.bytesToString(initialMemoryThreshold)} for computing block $blockId in memory.")
} else {
  unrollMemoryUsedByThisBlock += initialMemoryThreshold
}
```

So either you enable OFF_HEAP at your application level like it is done in this blog --> https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/apache-spark-off-heap-memory/read
Or you adjust your cluster/machine config and enable this setting as described here --> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management

And finally if none of the above helps, in my case rebooting the node got rid of the WARNINGS.